# how to add leading zeroes to some values?

Tags: r

My dataset includes 3 different types of values, two of them have dashes.

```
df=c("20001982-02", "19933626-02", "20024861-6", "29114-1", "20109774-02", 
"19965663-01", "19992655-01", "20087008-08", "140107", "20032011-09", 
"139")
```

I need to add leading zeroes to the values that have a dash so they match pattern XXXXXXXX-XX

```
df.new =c("20001982-02", "19933626-02", "20024861-06", "00029114-01", 
"20109774-02", "19965663-01", "19992655-01", "20087008-08", "140107", "20032011-09", "139")
```

So far i have this but only does part of the job (see 3rd element as i need it to be 00029114-01)

```
sub("^(\\d{8})-(\\d)$", "\\1-0\\2", df)

df.new = c("20001982-02", "19933626-02", "20024861-06", "29114-1", "20109774-02", 
"19965663-01", "19992655-01", "20087008-08", "140107", "20032011-09", 
"139")
```

Comment: Do you mean leading zeroes? The title says trailing, but in the second snippet it looks like you are adding leading and not trailing zeros.

Comment: sorry. messed up. yes: leading

Comment: which one is your expected outpu

Comment: `df.new =c("20001982-02", "19933626-02", "20024861-06", "00029114-01", 
"20109774-02", "19965663-01", "19992655-01", "20087008-08", "140107", "20032011-09", "139")`

Comment: Can you check my soltuion now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- sub("-(\\d$)", "-0\\1", df)
df2 <- ifelse(grepl("-\\d", df1), 
              str_pad(df1, width = 11, side = "left", pad = "0"), 
              df1)
 [1] "20001982-02" "19933626-02" "20024861-06" "00029114-01" "20109774-02" "19965663-01" "19992655-01" "20087008-08"
 [9] "140107"      "20032011-09" "139"
```

Comment: it doesnt :( 
Values like 19915484-2 do change but Values like 53846-01 remain the same . I need 00053846-01 instead

Answer (score 2):

We can use `grepl` with `sprintf` from `base R`.  Split the dataset at `-` with `read.table`, use `sprintf` to join back into a single string specifying the `fmt` for adding the leading zeros, create the condition in `ifelse` to return that new format when there is `-` or else the old one

```
out <- ifelse(grepl('-', df), do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = '%08d-%02d', 
 read.table(text = df, header = FALSE, sep="-", fill = TRUE))), df)
identical(df.new, out)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Trying to make it work as i get errors `Error in rep(no, length.out = length(ans)) : 
  attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'`

Comment: @AndresMora I don't get any errors with your df showed

Comment: after some testing, i found a flaw to this approach. see my report in a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67675116/how-to-add-leading-zeroes-based-on-pattern

Answer (score 0):

`stingr::pad()` is great for this.

```r
library(stringr)

df_dash <- df.new[grepl("-", df.new)]
```

## Leading zeros

```r
str_pad(df_dash, width = 11, pad = 0)
#> [1] "20001982-02" "19933626-02" "20024861-06" "00029114-01" "20109774-02"
#> [6] "19965663-01" "19992655-01" "20087008-08" "20032011-09"
```

Wrap it in `ifelse()` to return the original character vector with intended modifications.

```r
ifelse(grepl("-", df.new), str_pad(df.new, width = 11, pad = 0), df.new)
#>  [1] "20001982-02" "19933626-02" "20024861-06" "00029114-01" "20109774-02"
#>  [6] "19965663-01" "19992655-01" "20087008-08" "140107"      "20032011-09"
#> [11] "139"
```

## Trailing zeros

```r
split_strings <- strsplit(df_dash, "-")
sapply(split_strings, function(x) paste(str_pad(x[1], width = 8, side = "right",  pad = 0), x[2], sep = "-"))
#> [1] "20001982-02" "19933626-02" "20024861-06" "29114000-01" "20109774-02"
#> [6] "19965663-01" "19992655-01" "20087008-08" "20032011-09"
```

Comment: thanks. splitting the values based on the dash will not be convenient in my case as there are some values with no dash

Comment: The part of my answer that shows how to add leading zeros creates the exact output you are looking for if you execute the `ifelse()` line and does not include any string splitting. I left the part for trailing zeros in there, as it was part of your original question. Just in case the downvote came from you, please reconsider at least removing the downvote. Thanks!