# How to add leading zeroes based on pattern?

Tags: r

I have the following dataset and this code that will add leading zeroes to the values that come with a dash, leaving them with a XXXXXXXX-XX pattern. it partially works:

```
df.direccionamientos = structure(list(D_CodSerTecAEntregar = c("139",
                                                               "20018219-1", 
                                                               "2019-1", 
                                                               "20018219-1"
                                                               
                                                               )), 
                                 .Names = "D_CodSerTecAEntregar", 
                                 row.names = c(NA, -4L),
                                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#Leading zeroes
df.direccionamientos$D_CodSerTecAEntregar1 <- ifelse(grepl('-', df.direccionamientos$D_CodSerTecAEntregar), 
                                                      do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = '%08d-%02d', 
                                                                         read.table(text = df.direccionamientos$D_CodSerTecAEntregar,
                                                                                    header = FALSE, sep="-", 
                                                                                    fill = TRUE))), 
                                                     df.direccionamientos$D_CodSerTecAEntregar)
```

[image: output1]

But, this gets complicated when a new value with a different pattern passes through the code (see row 5 from new dataset). It messes up all of the newly created codes:

```
df.direccionamientos = structure(list(D_CodSerTecAEntregar = c("139",
                                                               "20018219-1", 
                                                               "2019-1", 
                                                               "20018219-1",
                                                               "1R1033181000100"
                                                               
                                                               )), 
                                 .Names = "D_CodSerTecAEntregar", 
                                 row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


#Leading zeroes
df.direccionamientos$D_CodSerTecAEntregar1 <- ifelse(grepl('-', df.direccionamientos$D_CodSerTecAEntregar), 
                                                      do.call(sprintf, c(fmt = '%08d-%02d', 
                                                                         read.table(text = df.direccionamientos$D_CodSerTecAEntregar,
                                                                                    header = FALSE, sep="-", 
                                                                                    fill = TRUE))), 
                                                     df.direccionamientos$D_CodSerTecAEntregar)
```

[image: output2]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when there are letters in the input, the fields cannot be automatically converted to integers before `sprintf` is applied. Here's a simplification using `tidyr` and `dplyr` that corrects the issue (and should be more efficient):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df.direccionamientos %>%
  separate(D_CodSerTecAEntregar, sep = "-", into = c("a", "b"), remove = FALSE, fill = "right") %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(a, b), as.integer),
    result = ifelse(!is.na(b), sprintf("%08d-%02d", a, b), D_CodSerTecAEntregar)
  ) %>%
  select(-a, -b)
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   D_CodSerTecAEntregar result         
#   <chr>                <chr>          
# 1 139                  139            
# 2 20018219-1           20018219-01    
# 3 2019-1               00002019-01    
# 4 20018219-1           20018219-01    
# 5 1R1033181000100      1R1033181000100
```

Comment: thanks. i like your approach but getting errors when trying to run over the sample dataset.  
`Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `result`.`
`result = ifelse(!is.na(b), sprintf("%08d-%02d", a, b), D_CodSerTecAEntregar)`.`
`x invalid format '%02d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects`

Comment: Hmm, try changing `as.numeric` to `as.integer`.